# Executing Visual Basic Macro (from personal macro workbook) in Python

Tags: python, vba

I'm trying to execute a visual basic script that is located in my personal macro workbook on an excel file that I'm creating. Here's what I have so far:

```
import os
import win32com.client
df2.to_excel("Apartments.xlsx")
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.open(filename="C:\Users\my\full\path\Apartments.xlsx", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("Apartments.xlsx!create_chart.create_chart_proc")
```

It's throwing an error when opening the excel file on line 5, I have a feeling line 6 won't work either because it comes from my personal macro book. Anyone have ideas on how to get it to function?

PS. my module name is "create_chart" and my macro name is "create_chart_proc"

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you said what error you are getting, and I know that this path

```
"C:\Users\my\full\path\Apartments.xlsx"
```

is not really what is in your code. But `\` inside a string has a special meaning in Python (for example `\n` is a newline and `\f` is a formfeed). Whether your `\` is interpreted as you intend depends on the character that comes after it. When you use Windows paths in Python it's generally less error-prone to use a raw string.

```
r"C:\Users\my\full\path\Apartments.xlsx"
```

When you get that line to work, if the next line gives trouble, then post that as a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, the error is as follows:TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'

Comment: Are you saying to have the code read like this?: xl.Workbooks.open(filename=r"C:\Users\my\full\path\Apartments.xlsx", ReadOnly=1)

Answer (score 0):

I got the first part of the code to work simply running the code as follows:

```
xl.workbooks.open("C:\Users\my\full\path\Apartments.xlsx")
```

Posted a separate question to get the macro to work correctly.